# Docker exec/run shell command nesting

Tags: bash, docker

A short introduction to the use case:

I am using a `docker` container to run my `go` tests using `go test ./...`. This can be achieved easily using `docker exec <container> /bin/sh -c "go test ./..."`. Unfortunately `go test ./...` runs across all subdirectories and I'd like to exclude one (the vendor directory).

The advised solution for this is using the following command: `go test $(go list ./... | grep -v '<excluded>'`, somehow this leaves me with the following result:

`docker run golang:1.6.2-alpine /bin/sh -c "go test "` (I have tested this on both run and exec, but they probably use the same core).

When I ssh into the container using `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh` and run the exact same command, it works like a charm.

It seems that executing shell commands trough the docker exec/run does not support any commands nested with `$()`?

Comment: What exactly command did you run? In `$(go list ./... | grep -v '<excluded>'`, what's `<excluded>` is?

Comment: It's a directory, `vendor` for example.

Comment: OK, so note that `$(...)` was expanded by your shell inside double quotes before it was run inside docker container. So, the issue may come from your current directory content. Did `docker exec container /bin/sh -c 'go test $(go list ./... | grep -v "<excluded>")'` work?

Comment: Why not run the commands [from a script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31578527/2777965)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your command may not be working as you expected thanks to a common bash gotcha:

```
docker exec <container> /bin/sh -c "go test $(go list ./... | grep -v '<excluded>')"
```

The command you are trying to run will perform the expansion of the subshell `$()` on your host because it is inside double quotes.

This can be solved by single quoting your command as suggested by @cuonglm in the question comments.

```
docker exec <container> /bin/sh -c 'go test $(go list ./... | grep -v "<excluded>")'
```

EDIT: A little demo

```
[wbarnwell@host ~]$ docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh -c '$(whoami)'
/bin/sh: root: not found
[wbarnwell@host ~]$ docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh -c "$(whoami)"
/bin/sh: wbarnwell: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

From `go test --help`:

```
-run regexp     Run only those tests and examples matching the regular
                expression.
```

So I guess something like `go test -run "(!vendor)" ./...` would skip that particular folder.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, this works! Unfortunately it does list all directories in which it does not match any tests - listing the entire vendor directory with "no test files".

Comment: Well, you can always filter those: `$(go test -run "(!vendor)" ./... | egrep -v "no test files\|vendor")`